# Multiproject Template - Adding solution folder and assemblies in a solution

Tags: project-template

I am able to create a multiple project using vstemplate and using IWizard to implement project name name conversion but I cannot able to add a solution folder and assemblies into it in RunCompleted method of IWizard. I am using Visual Studio 2010 for developement

Currenly I am trying to use the following code

```
$SolutionFolder folder = ((EnvDTE80.Solution2)dte.Solution).AddSolutionFolder("Test2").Object;
folder.AddFromFile("C:\\Liquid.dll");
```

dte is assigned during RunStarted method

```
$dte = automationObject as EnvDTE.DTE;
```

I can find the Test2 folder in the solution, but cannot find the dll file inside the solution folder, also I cannot find the physical folder(Test2) present inside the solution

Can anyone help me on this?